# Sending Telegram message from Python

Tags: python, linux, telegram

I want to send a message from a Python script via Telegram. 
I have tried to do that via telegram-cli, both the [original version from vysheng](https://github.com/vysheng/tg) and the [patched version from luckydonald](https://bitbucket.org/luckydonald/tg-for-pytg2). With both of them I could successfully send messages to my phone.
My problem is that:

- pytg2 didn't install cleanly (import DictObject fails, apparently author has this on pypi separately, but I stopped at that point), required Python 3 (unlike the rest of my project, but semi-acceptable) and can do a lot more than I need.
- I cannot get input into the tg console environment that is then executed there. Inputting via `<<EOF ... EOF` as in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330922/sending-messages-with-telegram-apis-or-cli) failed; the program opens on console, but doesn't output anything.
- Opening a port via -P option worked. I could then operate from nc environment (similar to [tg wiki](https://github.com/vysheng/tg/wiki/Running-as-daemon)), but I'm not sure if it is wise to implement all these calls in my Python script.
- I also found another script that echoes commands into tg (forgot source), but it didn't work either (similar behavior to `<<EOF` above)

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  to=Matthias_SG
  msg="test message"
  tgpath=/home/matthias/dvl/tg
  cd ${tgpath}
  (echo "add_contact +xxx Matthias SG"; echo "msg $to $msg") | ${tgpath}/bin/telegram-cli -k tg-server.pub
  ```

So my question is:
Should I go back to the older pytg? Can I fix the shell scripts or amend them to Python by inputting a stringIO from subprocess.call or popen? Is anyone out there using this in a robust fashion?

#### Background

- http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-remote-control-with-Telegram/ showing how to reply to a 'ping' message with a 'pong' message using a Lua script. Worked for me.
- http://technofaq.org/posts/2014/06/chat-with-telegram-buddies-the-geeky-way-with-telegram-cli/

Answer (score 46):

The first step is to create a [bot](https://core.telegram.org/bots#6-botfather) and get the `token`.

The second step is go get the `chat_id`:

- Write something in the chat
- Visit `https://api.telegram.org/bot<YourBOTToken>/getUpdates` and get the `chat_id` under the key `message['chat']['id']`.

The last step is to use this code:

```py
import requests

def telegram_bot_sendtext(bot_message):

   bot_token = ''
   bot_chatID = ''
   send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + bot_message

   response = requests.get(send_text)

   return response.json()


test = telegram_bot_sendtext("Testing Telegram bot")
print(test)
```

Code extracted from [Medium.com: How to create a Telegram bot, and send messages with Python](https://medium.com/@ManHay_Hong/how-to-create-a-telegram-bot-and-send-messages-with-python-4cf314d9fa3e)

Answer (score 3):

1. Talk to [`@BotFather`](https://t.me/BotFather). Send `/newbot` to them and follow the prompts. In response you will get an HTTP API token (it will look something like `123456:ABC-DEF1234ghIkl-zyx57W2v1u123ew11`).
2. Talk to your newly created bot, it is enough to just `/start` it.
3. Immediately open `https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/getUpdates?offset=-1` in your web-browser (literally paste the token you received from the BotFather, complete with all the letters and punctuation). Copy the chat id from the returned JSON object.
4. With the data above, sending a message is a matter of a simple POST request.

   For example, using the [Requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/) library:

   ```py
   import requests

   TOKEN = '...'
   CHAT_ID = '...'
   SEND_URL = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendMessage'

   requests.post(SEND_URL, json={'chat_id': CHAT_ID, 'text': your_message})
   ```

Comment: I try this and it worked. My doubt: can I only send messages to the created bot? Can I do it to another chat? If so, how can I get the chat_id of it?

Comment: @MarioMey you do not send messages to the bot, you send messages _from_ the bot to users who activated it. You can get `chat_id`s from your program by using that same `getUpdates` endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather use the package `python-telegram-bot`, it works well for me.

You can find [here](https://python-telegram-bot.org) documentation and an easy example to get started.

In order to reply to text messages, you can add a MessageHandler after the CommandHandler such as:

```
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, text_reply))

def text_reply(bot, updater):
    text = update.message.text

    if text == 'ping':
        reply = 'pong'

    elif text == 'pong':
        reply = 'ping'

    # add any process to the text

    else:
        reply = "I only respond to ping pong"

    update.message.reply_text(reply)
```

Don't forget to import `from telegram.ext import MessageHandler`.

Hope this helped!