# Adding chat functionality to a game using telegram api

Tags: chat, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to add chat functionality to a game I have developed using Unity, and I'm going to use Telegram for that. I didn't found telegram api documentation enough helpful, and it seemed to have steep learning curve specially for advanced features.

So I searched for something that could give me a high level tool, and I found [Telegram Cli](https://github.com/vysheng/tg) ([also in Python](https://github.com/luckydonald/pytg)) and [Telegram Bot Api](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api). But I don't know that they can be used to develop a chat app. Telgeram Bot is suggesting that is used for creating telgeram bots, not chat app instances. Also Telegram Cli seemed to be a command line version of desktop app.

Anyway what I want to add is chatting with friends, adding other players to friend list, and other thing that a chat application has.

My question is: Can I use either telgeram bot api or telegram cli to create something like a chat application? or I have to use Telegram Api and MTProto?
If I have to use the second method, I would really appreciate some sample code or a simple guide.

Also I have read other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330922/sending-messages-with-telegram-apis-or-cli) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661644/how-to-implement-authorization-using-a-telegram-api). Second one is really good, but I don't understand VB.net. Some C-Like language or python is really better.

and I have read documentation pages like [Creating an Authorization Key (Sample)](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/samples-auth_key) or [Creating an Authentication Key](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/auth_key), and they weren't enough helpful. TL Language is quite complicated too (IMHO).

**Edit:** Since it might be ambiguous, I want to use Telegram Api to add chat In my game.

Answer (score 2):

you didn't mention specifically if you want players to chat inside your app or out of your app in telegram?

1. **out of your app**: well, you could just create `telegram.me/username` links inside your app and when a user clicks it. Telegram app would open and he would start chatting with the opponent just right away. 
   this method is:

   - easy (no special coding required)
   - familiar UI
   - not limited to game users
   - some might not have telegram installed already and would be forced to download and extra app to use your game
   - it would be out of your control (who knows when their service might not )
2. **inside your app**:  you'd have to write your own telegram client, which is not easy and going by telegram rules, like getting pin codes for signing in and other stuff, I don't think it would work for you. Instead if you try to write your own game messaging system yourself, I guess you'll spend less time and get better results.

   - good amount of coding
   - have to go by an extra signing process for users
   - need to keep up with updates and changes

Comment: I just want to use the api inside my app. but my question is can i use telegram cli or telegram bot api? (sorry i forgot to add links to the projects in my question. it is now added.)

Comment: well, It's not a good choice, your users will have to go through another step to sign in into their telegram account. I suggest you would just be better off using your own messaging system.