# Telegram-cli needs libconfig +pythonanywhere

Tags: linux, bash, telegram, user-permissions, pythonanywhere

I want to use telegram-cli for my project that Im hosting at pythonanywhere.com. But i dont have root permission so cannot use apt-get, what options do I have?
Clone github.com/hyperrealm/libconfig and then do make? and then how add the path?

Comment: Maybe one of the answers found here will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330922/sending-messages-with-telegram-apis-or-cli

Comment: @RuudHelderman thanks will help later but my problem is that i haven't the libconfing-dev installed and i cant just sudo apt-get because im not root, so i dont know how to intall telegram-cli